# PHP not recognizing sqlsrv

Tags: php, sql-server, windows, sqlsrv

So far, I've followed the steps outlined in this tutorial: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/windows However, the php version listed was not avaiable, so I went with PHP 7.3, and I've been using the 5.6 PHP for SQL Server drivers with it. The problem is that when I run the sample connect.php, it returns `Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\db.php on line 12` I understand that this is because PHP doesn't recognize sqlsrv as a module.

When I run `php -d display_startup_errors=1 -d error_reporting=-1 -d display_errors -c "C:\Path\To\php.ini" -m` it doesn't display sqlsrv, as expected, but I'm not sure what's causing this problem.

I call both `php_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll` and `php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll` in the ext folder in the php.ini-production file as `;extension=php_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64.dll`.

This isn't working, so I've tried using the threaded instead of non_threaded versions as well but it still isn't recognizing sqlsrv as a module. I don't know if it might have something to do with how I'm placing the extension statements in the php.ini-production file, but here is how it is placed. https://i.stack.imgur.com/efg8q.png

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you uncomment the includes? remove the `;` from the front of the string? `;extension=php_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64.dll`

Answer (score 0):

The following method was used by me in order correctly configure IIS with PHP using fastCGI. (Hope you have already configured PHP With IIS Server).

1. The easiest way to rectify the error is to use PHP Configuration coming with XAAMP. After XAAMP installation, copy the php folder to a place you like (C:\xampp\php)
2. Then download and install PHP Manager for IIS - https://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2018/05/php-manager-150-for-iis-10
3. If Open, close the IIS Manager and Reopen, PHP Manager is available. PHP Manager will help you to easily configure PHP With IIS and install the External drivers hassle free.
4. Just Go through the PHP Manager options and you can get a good idea. To reconfigure the PHP Version, click register new version and select php-cgi.exe inside the php folder mentioned in step one. Also without copy and pasting you can use PHP Manager to install Drivers easily as well.
5. At last install Microsoft SQL ODBC Drivers as well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

lines that start with `;` in your php.ini file are commented out and so are not read by php.  Uncomment one or both of those lines to use the extension.